How to truncate file from top to have file only of certain size in Perl
I have a file (file.txt). Data gets appended on it every minute. Now, the fie size is getting higher and higher. What I want is that whenever the file size crosses 800MB size, all the lines from the top gets deleted. How can this be done in perl?

what operating system? what filesystem?

If you're on a unixy system, use logrotate

This seems to be based on a common beginner misconception about how files are organized. On most systems, the only way to "truncate from the beginning" is to rewrite the entire file, starting from the first byte you want to keep. No common file system has any operation to move the start of the file to a new place without rewriting it.

@triplee linux has fallocate(2) with FALLOC_FL_COLLAPSE_RANGE but granularity may be restricted to multiple of logical block size

Right, I should perhaps have said "to an arbitrary new position", which is usually what beginners want.

Seek to a point 800mb from the end. Find the start of a log entry near that point. Write everything from there to the end of a file to a temporary one and replace the original with it. Have a way to prevent more log entries from being written while you're doing this. Make sure new log entries are written to the new file when you're done and not still to the previous one.

Untested, truncate from beginning by 1024 bytes. fallocate -v -p -o 0 -l 1024 file.txt

In the below code, whenever the size of file (/home/file.txt)   crosses 724775731 bytes, all lines except last 3000000 files would be deleted.
use strict;
use warnings;

my $fileToClean="/home/file.txt";
if (-s "${fileToClean}" > 724775731) {
    print "$fileToClean is going to be cleaned now as it has crossed the desired file size\n";
    `echo -e '1,-3000000d\nwq' | ed $fileToClean`
}


-s returns the size in bytes, not kilobytes.

You are also assigning a variable $sizeInKbs (wrong name) but never use it. Instead you do the file check twice. And that shell command looks very funky, but unfortunately I cannot decipher it.
